# Problem in using wpdb

Tags: database, wpdb, errors

I used "wpdb" in my code  But it was not working and the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" in tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'complaint';

```
global $wpdb;
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $dis = $_POST["dis"];
    $code = $_POST["code"];
    
function insert_record_to_db($name,$email,$dis){
    global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'complaint';
    $data=array( 
            'name' => '$name',
            'email' => '$email',
            'dis' => '$dis'
        );
    $format= array('%s','%s','%s');
    
    $wpdb->insert( $tablename , $data , $format );
};
insert_record_to_db($name,$email,$dis);
```

Comment: Firstly, remove the quotes around the variables in the $data array. Secondly, you have much more $format than $data elements.

Comment: where is this code and when do you try to call it?

Answer (score 2):

This error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object

Means that `$wpdb` isn't instantiated so you are running your code too early or out of WordPress context-- for example, in an exterior PHP file accessed directly, which is what I suspect (Poorly conceived AJAX request perhaps?).

As mentioned, the code has more formats that data elements and your single quotes are going to cause this fail (in a sense) anyway as you will literally be inserting "$email" and "$name" strings into the database.

```
function insert_record_to_db($name,$email,$dis){
  global $wpdb;
  $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'complaint';
  $data=array( 
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'dis' => $dis
  );
  $format= array('%s','%s','%s');
  $wpdb->insert( $tablename , $data , $format );
};
insert_record_to_db('a','b','c');
```